# Styling Android EditText

Tags: android, styling

I'm trying to style edit text widgets in my app. Right now if I use this:

```
<style name="MyEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/input_text</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
</style>
```

It will show black background on phone I use for testing. I'd like to get something that looks the same everywhere. I think I will be OK with this style (I also believe this is "standard"). How do I pull this stale or should I make my own somehow?

[image]

EDIT:

Here is my code for TextEdit

```
<EditText
                style="@style/MyEditText"
                android:id="@+id/et_serverURL" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:maxLength="25"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext" android:singleLine="true" android:inputType="textUri"
                android:hint="@string/str_login_activity_server_url_hint"

                />
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't very good understand English. As I understood your problem that view draws black background? It's so? Just to I can help you.

Comment: Yes. Its like regular textbox with black background

Comment: Why you don't want to set your background image? You can set it in custom style so you be sure that on all devices it will looks same

Comment: If you want just draw bottom line then you can just override background drawing on custom it's very easy

Answer (score 0):

The style shown in your image is called Holo. You can use it like so

```
<style name="MyEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.EditText">
<!-- Your custom attributes here -->
</style>
```

**EDIT**

If you want your app to use your themes as you have them right now but have your `EditText` be `Holo` then you can override the `<item name="android:editTextStyle"></item>`under your current theme to use `MyEditText` instead of the default parent style. Then set your theme either to your activity, or to your application.

Comment: Hmm. Strange. Is it possible this style not included in distribution? I have Samsung Galaxy tab 3 from Sprint. It does work on emulator.

Comment: Can you post some code on how you're implementing 'MyEditText'

Comment: Done. I tried to make change to App theme (created style and added to manifest) and it worked

Comment: Style "Holo" didn't include in distribution of old devices. So, if u need to support it too you should declare few styles for different versions.

Comment: @Pztar yes, it works but after I set app-wide style. If I just try to style this widget as in main topic - it doesn't work

Comment: @ghostman I don't mind declaring styles, just not sure how to create one to make it look like so.

Comment: @katit you don't have to set it across your entire app. You can set it for just your current activity

Comment: Understood. But I still like to figure out how to style specific widget

Comment: Maybe it doesn't suit for you but why you don't use Android Support libraries. It fixes a lot of problem with styling and it's easier to override on custom styles